# Does anybody recognize this scheduling problem? Is there an algorithm for it?

Tags: algorithms, problem-solving, scheduling

Consider the following problem:

---

**Description**:

There are n jobs J<sub>1</sub>...J<sub>n</sub> with cycle times C<sub>1</sub>....C<sub>n</sub>. Find a *time quantum* and a scheduling table considering that:

- any element of the table contains at most one job
- the job handler will process an element at a time, i.e. execute the job (if any) then, after a *time quantum* passes, moves to the next element.
- the job handler will loop-back, i.e. after the last element it will continue with the first.
- the ciclicity must be maintained, i.e. the distance between any two consecutive (including loop-back) occurances of job J<sub>k</sub> (k = 1,n) must be equal to C<sub>k</sub> / *time quantum*.
- the table must be as short as possible.

**Example**:

- J<sub>1</sub> - 4 seconds ciclicity
- J<sub>2</sub> - 6 seconds ciclicity
- J<sub>3</sub> - 8 seconds ciclicity

**Example solution**:

time quantum = 1s

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 seconds
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|J1|J2|J3|  |J1|  |  |J2|J1|  |J3|  |J1|J2|  |  |J1|  |J3|J2|J1|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

---

My feeling is that this belongs to the family of scheduling problems and that it may be a special case of a more general problem. **Is this so?**
 I tried to search for it online but didn't find anything that looks similar.
 Since I don't have any experience with scheduling problems I'm not even sure what to search for.

From what I see:

- the total duration of the schedluing table should be the smallest common multiple of C<sub>1</sub>...C<sub>n</sub>.
- the time quantum should be at least GCD(C<sub>1</sub>,...,C<sub>n</sub>) / n. - This is not necessarly the optimal solution.

This leads me to believe that there is a straight forward solution and not one involving dynamic programming. **Is this so?**

Can somebody point me to some resources, maybe even an algorithm, for this problem?

I'm also curious about variations where there the jobs can be distributed between more than one scheduling tables.

---

GCD = Greatest Common Divider

**Edit**: I'm not asking how to schedule N jobs with given cycle times; I'm sure there are more dynamic ways to do this as some suggested. My problem is "*Find a time quantum and a scheduling table considering that:[...]*". It's even possible that it may have it's roots in some parts of mathematics.

Comment: if this is a homework assignment, first thing to search would be not _online_, but course materials. Did you check these? Did you ask your tutor, what did they say?

Comment: @gnat It is not a homework assignement. In my case the *jobs* are the sending of cyclic messages on CAN bus.

Comment: @gnat I don't agree with your edit. I specifically written the question in the form of a general problem. It's nature has nothing specific to CAN communication. The title is especially misleading.

Comment: as long as you're looking for someone to _recognize_ a problem, it would increase your chances to find someone who already has dealt with this kind of application

Comment: @gnat I would argue the other way, you are making it more specialized. The CAN protocol is used mostly in the automotive industry and I'm sure they are a minority here. As I said the problem is not specific to CAN communications, I've encountered it at other times.

Comment: I'm certain there is a class of such problems that could be scheduled without a conflict, but in cases where there are conflicts, how should they be handled?

Comment: @Blackhawk The way that I've described the problem there will always be a solution. For example lets take 2 jobs with cycle times 2s and 3s. The time table shall be at least 6s long, but because GCD(2s,3s) = 1s you are guaranteed a collision if *tq* is 1s or larger.The trick is that you can divide the GCD by the total number of jobs, in this way creating separate "*tracks*" for each job. You ca do this if there are no restriction on *tq* and, of course, the solution will not necessarily be optimal.

Comment: Wouldn't that example collide? Suppose I've got job "a" with a 3s cycle and job "b" with a 2s cycle; tq = 1s.  The table might be |a|b| |?|...  Assuming a would be ready to go again AND b would be ready to go again, but only one can be started, that means one has to sit idle.

Comment: @Blackhawk As I've said "*[...] you are guaranteed a collision if tq is 1s or larger*". But I can choose a smaller *tq* granted that there are no restrictions on *tq* (as in the description of the problem). Try it with *tq* = 0.5s and you will see that there is a solution.

Comment: Ah! Gotcha, I was under the mistaken assumption that it had to be an integer number of seconds based on the discussion so far.

Comment: /* A nitpick: _quanta_ is plural for _quantum;_ "a quanta" sounds weird. */

Comment: Kinda necro-posting, but whatever. It seems to me that an easy procedure would be to divide the job cycles by their GCD (call it `g`, also call the SCM `s`), in the resulting numbers find the largest co-prime group of numbers (denote the size by `n`). Then the maximum quanta will be `g/n` and the minimum table size will be `s*n`. Building the table itself will then be a simple linear sweep. (This also fits with the example - `n=2`, `g=2` and `s=12`, so the quanta is 1 and the table size is 24)

Answer (score 1):

You could determine the best schedule using a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).  Where are the decision moments in scheduling?  It is when you have more than one cycle to start on any given second.

You'll need to have a "schedule" data type representing a possible schedule (the data you've written above is a perfect example of the data you'd represent here).

Therefore the pseudo algorithm should be the following:

Add each cycle type to its own schedule and push each schedule onto a priority queue, prioritizing by smallest GCD*(C1,...,Cn) / n value.

Then, starting with the schedule with the smallest GCD*(C1,...,Cn) / n value, create new schedules from the old by appending new cycles to launch.

Continue for as much as you like.

You decide when the schedule should end, and since it is a priority queue, you're guaranteed that the first element is the optimal in terms of GCD*(C1,...,Cn) / n at any given point.

Hope that helps.